# unable to position elements using backwards compatible CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to position a content inside div.

The idea is to make it cross browser compatible, so I am trying to avoid the use of flex. I would like to find a solution using compatible CSS

[image: card]

and the CSS I am using

```
.tu-plus-wrapper {
    &__helper {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    &__logo{
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    &__content {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;

        &__points {
            font-family: $RobotoLight;
            font-size: 2.4rem;
            line-height: 36px;
        }

        &__text {
            font-family: $RobotoRegular;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to align the logo vertically and the right side content to the far right of parent div, but there is some kind of style collision. I would appreciate some CSS magic here.

and of course the html structure:

```
<div class="tu-plus-wrapper">
    <span class="tu-plus-wrapper__helper"></span>
    <img class="tu-plus-wrapper__logo" src="assets/imgs/tuplus/tuplus.svg">
    <div class="tu-plus-wrapper__content">
        <div class="tu-plus-wrapper__content__points">{{points}}</div>
        <div class="tu-plus-wrapper__content__text">Puntos</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

to push an element to the right, you can use `float: right`. Then to center vertically, one trick is to position the element with `top: -50%` and `transform: translateY(50%)`

```
.tu-plus-wrapper {
    position: relative;

    &__helper {
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }

    &__logo{
        position: relative;
        top: -50%;
        transform: translateY(50%);
    }

    &__content {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: right;
        right: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        float: right

        &__points {
            font-family: $RobotoLight;
            font-size: 2.4rem;
            line-height: 36px;
        }

        &__text {
            font-family: $RobotoRegular;
            font-size: 1.2rem;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
    }
}
```